# $\int_a^bf(x) dx=\int_a^bf^\prime(x) dx$

Tags: metric-spaces, compactness

I am facing problem in the following exercise. I don't know how to tackle this problem. Can anyone please help me?

[image]

The only thing I can say $$ \int_a^bf(x) dx=\int_a^bf^\prime(x) dx \implies \int_a^bf(x) dx=f(b)-f(a).  $$

Comment: **Hint**: $$\int_a^x f(t) \ dt = f(x) - f(a)$$
 implies

$f(x) = f'(x)$

Comment: Okay, I got it. This is the function $exp(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

There is only one function that fits this case (the questions implies D is true, so I'll run with it) which is that $f(x)=e^x$.  Therefore we must determine if the image of $f(x)$ (which is $\mathbb{R}^+$) is compact.  This leads in to a topological argument and that was a class that didn't go so well for me.

Comment: No, it's not compact, by Heine Borel

Comment: There are infinitely many functions: $a \cdot \exp x$.

Comment: So the answer would be not compact, since he is asking for the option which is not true. $ a \exp(x)$ is possible but only for a=1, since f(0)=1.